# Not able to see streets on google map at 15 to 15.9 zoom level Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a weird question actually. I am **not able to see the streets on the google map at 15 to 15.9 zoom level.** when I apply zoom between this level of range then google **shows black lines as streets** and which is quite different than Original Google Map.

Before 01-08-2016 my demo was looking perfect. But since 2-3 days it gives black thin lines as streets. whenever I give 16 or 14.9 zoom level it works perfectly.

I am using Normal Map. **In terrain it is working perfectly.**

I have downloaded a few apps from play store which work on google map. In those apps also I found the same thing.

It would be great if suggest any way to find out. why it is looking like this since last few days.

[image: In this picture you can see black thin lines as streets]

Comment: Did u read latest release for google map  [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#august_1_2016)

Comment: yes recently on 01-08 google updated map... And gave updates on camera listener.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your inquiry and found that there is no problem with your code. Just noticed that if the street has no name it shows a black line. Note that the zoom level of the camera determines the scale of the map. At larger [zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#zoom) more detail can be seen on the screen, while at smaller zoom levels more of the world can be seen on the screen. Can you please differeny
 The range of zoom levels permitted by the map depends on a number of factors including location, map type and screen size. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks datul
But before 2 weeks i was able to see that streets without black lines.
In fact, today also we are able to see that streets in terrain type map, the problem is only in normal map type since 1-8-2016.

Google Map(Original App) does't shows black lines, they shows entire streets on this zoom level.

Comment: I want to dig to your issue, can you expound more your issue?

Comment: it has been automatically resolved on 8th of August 2016.
Thanks for your support :) .